# Leetcode 393: UTF-8 Validation (Python)

Tags: python, list, bit

problem:

> Given an integer array data representing the data, return whether it
> is a valid UTF-8 encoding (i.e. it translates to a sequence of valid
> UTF-8 encoded characters).
>
> A character in UTF8 can be from 1 to 4 bytes long, subjected to the
> following rules:
>
> For a 1-byte character, the first bit is a 0, followed by its Unicode
> code. For an n-bytes character, the first n bits are all one's, the n
>
> - 1 bit is 0, followed by n - 1 bytes with the most significant 2 bits being 10. This is how the UTF-8 encoding would work:
>
>   Number of Bytes   |        UTF-8 Octet Sequence
>   |              (binary)
>   --------------------+-----------------------------------------
>   1          |   0xxxxxxx
>   2          |   110xxxxx 10xxxxxx
>   3          |   1110xxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx
>   4          |   11110xxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx
>   denotes a bit in the binary form of a byte that may be either 0 or 1.

I was trying to figure out this question. And one of the testcase is [250,145,145,145,145]. My code would return True, but the answer is False. My question is how is [250,145,145,145,145] a false?

250: 11111010
145: 10010001

Here is my code:

```
class Solution:
    def validUtf8(self, data: List[int]) -> bool:

        def bitfield(n, length=8):
            digits = bin(n)[2:]
            rtn = ['0' for i in range(8)]
            start = length - len(digits)
            for i in range(len(digits)):
                rtn[start] = digits[i]
                start += 1
            return rtn

        def check_byte_num(num: List[int]):
            if num[0] == '0':
                return 1
            cnt = 0
            for i in range(len(num)):
                if num[i] == '1':
                    cnt += 1
                else:
                    return cnt
            return cnt

        def check_follow_char(num: List[int]):
            if num[0] == '1' and num[1] == '0':
                return True
            else:
                return False

        idx = 0
        while idx < len(data):
            char_bit = bitfield(data[idx])
            if idx == len(data) - 1 and char_bit[0] != '0':
                return False

            char_num = check_byte_num(char_bit)

            char_num -= 1
            idx += 1
            while char_num > 0:
                if idx >= len(data):
                    return False
                if not check_follow_char(bitfield(data[idx])):
                    return False
                idx += 1
                char_num -= 1
        return True
```

Comment: Remember to [post a _full_ question](/help/how-to-ask): we're not going to look up what exercise you're looking at, instead please [edit] your post to describe what you're being asked to do. If leetcode drop off the internet tomorrow, your post should still make sense.

Comment: Note that, as mentioned, UTF-8 cannot be more than four bytes (at least right now). So a five or more byte value with a lead byte that's over 247 (`b11110111`), is by definition not UTF-8.